# Google Apps Script - Handling Result from UrlFetchApp.fetch()

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a spreadsheet that I only want users to modify by running a script.  The script is a UiApp that has a few pre-defined input fields and text boxes and the results are submitted onto the spreadsheet.  Because I only want the document modified from this app, I have to set the permissions of the spreadsheet to "Can comment."  However, in doing this, the users cannot run the script (because the script edits the page and they don't have editing rights to the page).  So I assume that I need to create a web app.

The web app would be stand-alone and would run as me (the owner) so that calls to the app would allow the submitted data to be written to the spreadsheet.  My web app looks something like this:

```
function doGet() {
   var app = UiApp.createApplication();
   // UiApp elements are added here
   return app;
 }
```

...and the works fine when the url is accessed directly from the browser.  However, I would like for the app to open w/i the spreadsheet from a spreadsheet trigger.  I was thinking something like this:

```
var app = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
ss.show(app);
```

...but this is not working.  The error I get is: "Invalid argument: userInterface (line 12, file "Web App")."  Line 12 is "ss.show(app)."  I was hoping that the app object would be returned from UrlFetch, but I now know that an HTTPResponse is returned.

How can I convert this response into a UiApp object?  Thanks.

Comment: One thing I tried was having the user trigger the app from the spreadsheet.  The app opens, takes the input, and then passes the data as parameters using UrlFetch.  This works when the data is basic/small, but does not work for a large amount of text and multiple fields of data.  Would passing the data as JSON work?  If so, how? (I am new to JSON.)

Comment: In the workflow you describe in the comments, how do the users access the webapp? Using an anchor that opens a new tab? If so , your app (running as you) could write directly to the spreadsheet that could be in view only for other users. If I misunderstood (I'm afraid I did) could you clarify your comment please?   As for what you describe in your answer, it is indeed not possible to have a function running under another identity in a SS , even if it uses a UI showing as modal or sidebar.

Comment: Hi Serge, I mocked up the workflow on [this spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1U0K4wShjR0HgSxMBGWuxHTju_7Y-WgEsKpPtSOu7hko/edit?usp=sharing). Basically, you click on a cell and then click "Custom > Input Support" from the custom menu.  Then the UIApp appears and the user selects from a few drop-downs and enters text.  Upon hitting submit, the cell is shaded, the cell's value has a 2-letter code, and a note is inserted with all the data.

Comment: I want the spreadsheet to be in a certain format for the users (shaded cells, 2-letter codes, and notes w/ the details), so that is why I would like for them to enter the data with the app.  The problem is that in order for the app to write to the cells, the user must have "Can edit" access because the app is container-bound. But I don't want this because I don't want them to modify the spreadsheet on their own.  That is why I thought that a stand-alone web app (that is executed by me [the owner]) would be the solution.  I just can't figure it out!

Comment: Also, the spreadsheet is "Can edit" for anyone with the link.  But if for some reason you cannot use the custom menu in order to see how it works, I can share the file with you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I came up with was to have the UiApp open on the spreadsheet (from a trigger) and have the user choose the drop-downs and complete the text boxes.  Upon clicking the submit button, the handler function would take all of the parameters and create a payload. Then this payload was passed to a doPost(e) stand-alone web app.  Because I passed the ssid, the web app was able to locate the spreadsheet/sheet/range and write/format the data in a certain way.  Here is my code:

```
var payload = {
   "ssid" : ssid,
   "sheetName" : sheetName,
   "row" : row,
   "col" : col,
   "method" : method,
   "strategy" : strategy,
   "summary" : summary,
};

var options = {
   "method" : "post",
   "payload" : payload
};

UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
```

This way the users can input the information in a certain format without having editing rights to the sheet.

Comment: Nice :-)  +1. Just a question :  what trigger do you use to start the UI?

Comment: Thanks!  The onOpen trigger installs the custom menu.  When the user wants to input the support, he/she clicks on the menu which executes the function.

Comment: In that case one can not say that at trigger "runs" the function, the user do (by clicking the menu item). The trigger only shows the menu.